# How to clear html video element when removing track

Tags: javascript, html5-video, getusermedia, mediastream

The following code does pretty much what I want:

```js
video = document.querySelector('video');
video.srcObject = new MediaStream();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(stream => {
  stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
    video.srcObject.addTrack(track);
  });
});

setTimeout(() => {
  video.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => {
    track.stop()
    video.srcObject.removeTrack(track);
  });
}, 5000);
```

It starts the camera and displays the result on screen. After 5 seconds the camera is stopped again. However, the last image from the camera remains as a freeze frame in the video. How can I clear the video element?

(Note that I only remove the video tracks, so there might still be audio tracks playing.)

EDIT: I messed up the audio part of the question. In the real code there *are* audio tracks that should keep playing, I just forgot to add them to the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is removing all the tracks from the MediaStream, not only the video ones.
To remove only the video ones, you'd do

```
video.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => {
  track.stop()
  video.srcObject.removeTrack(track);
});
```

Note how `getTracks` is replaced with `getVideoTracks`.

But even then, the last frame from the video track may very well still stay in the `<video>` element. To get rid of it, but keep the audio tracks, you'd be better creating a new MediaStream from the audio tracks and set this as the new srcObject of your `<video>`:

Code of [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x12aqpo8/) since StackSnippet's iframe aren't allowed to call getUserMedia.

```js
(async ()=>{

  const video = document.querySelector('video');
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true } );
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();

  btn.onclick = e => {
    stream.getVideoTracks().forEach( vidTrack => vidTrack.stop() );
    const new_stream = new MediaStream(stream.getAudioTracks());
    video.srcObject = new_stream;
    btn.remove();
  }

})();
```

```html
<button id="btn">keep only audio</button>
<video controls autoplay></video>
```

And if you wanted to replace it with a solid color (e.g a black frame), then you could pass a CanvasCaptureStreamTrack along with the audio tracks, and draw that solid color on the source `<canvas>`: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x12aqpo8/1)

Comment: The part about `getVideoTracks()` was my mistake, fixed it in the question. The rest sounds promising though. I will try if it fixes my issue.